# how to callback java method in C code(not jni method in c)?

Tags: java, c, callback, java-native-interface

i encounter a issue that how to **callback** java method in C method, this c method unlike JNI generate c method. not include **JNIEnv** and **JObject** parameter in the parameter list. How to solve it or something else workaround....

Answer (score 1):

To execute a Java method from C program you need to load JVM into C program first. For that you should use the Invocation API, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html

Comment: +1 I can second that: I have code in production that does exactly this.

Comment: Yes, i know that way. But this C code compiled by NDK, it throws undefined reference to  'JNI_CreateJavaVM'.

Answer (score 0):

This method will create its own JNI_CreateJavaVM method and attach it as a thread then releases it right after using it.

Load jvm.dll installed in your computer

```
TCHAR* dllpath = (char*)TEXT("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_65\\jre\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll");
HMODULE jniModule = LoadLibrary(dllpath);
```

Define the function to create JVM

```
typedef int (JNICALL * JNI_CreateJavaVM)(JavaVM** jvm, JNIEnv** env, JavaVMInitArgs* initargs);
JNI_CreateJavaVM createJavaVM = (JNI_CreateJavaVM)GetProcAddress(jniModule, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
```

Create the JVM

```
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
options[0].optionString = const_cast<char*>("-Djava.class.path=" USER_CLASSPATH);

JavaVMInitArgs initArgs;
initArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
initArgs.nOptions = 1;
initArgs.options = options;
JavaVM* jvm;
JNIEnv* env;
DWORD retval;
if ((retval = createJavaVM(&jvm, &env, &initArgs)) != JNI_OK){
    cout << "beyond the scope of this answer" << endl;
    return 1;
}
jint retvalue = jvm->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
bool mustDetach = false;
```

Detach your JVM if necessary

```
if (retvalue == JNI_EDETACHED)
    {
        JavaVMAttachArgs args;
        args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
        args.name = NULL;
        args.group = NULL;
        retvalue = jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void**)&env, &args);
        mustDetach = true; // to clean up afterwards
    }
```

Point to your target Java class where the method is located

```
jclass clazz = env->FindClass("MyClazz");
```

Point to the java method

```
jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(clazz, "myJavaMethod", "()I");
```

Invoke the java method

```
int returnedValue = env->CallStaticintMethod(clazz, mid);

cout << "Returned value is " << returnedValue->size << endl;
```

This will not throw undefined reference to  JNI_CreateJavaVM